# How to get videoId of Vimeo with Regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I try to get the id of the Vimeo video via Javascript Regex. However, the output will be: http://vimeo.com/169473112,169473112

How can I access everything after the comma?
https://jsfiddle.net/v9y4a0zo/

```
var videoId ='http://vimeo.com/169473112';
var REGEX = /vimeo.*(?:\/|clip_id=)([0-9a-z]*)/i;
var $body = document.querySelector('body');

var parsed = videoId.match(REGEX) + '<br />';
$body.innerHTML += parsed;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could `exec()` the Regex, then get the second match and show it, like so:

```
var videoId ='http://vimeo.com/169473112';
var regExp = /vimeo.*(?:\/|clip_id=)([0-9a-z]*)/i;
var $body = document.querySelector('body');

var parsed = regExp.exec(videoId);
$body.innerHTML += parsed[1] + '<br />';
```

Check it out live in this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v9y4a0zo/).

By the way, if you do not want to alter your code that much, you can always do this:

```
var videoId ='http://vimeo.com/169473112';
var REGEX = /vimeo.*(?:\/|clip_id=)([0-9a-z]*)/i;
var $body = document.querySelector('body');

var parsed = videoId.match(REGEX)[1] + '<br />';
$body.innerHTML += parsed;
```

Live in this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v9y4a0zo/1/).

The whole problem revolves around the fact that you get the whole matches list, which includes the original string, thus if you get the second match, you will get the part you want.

Answer (score 1):

VideoId.match return array object, so your ID is at first index:

```
var parsed = videoId.match(regExp)[1] + '<br />';
```

But you should probably test, if this index exists (if the link is valid). :)